# Unable to serve.terrain files in cesium sandcastle

Tags: javascript, webgl, cesiumjs

I am learning 3d terrain generation using CesiumJS. I generated .terrain files usind [Cesium terrain builder](https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-builder) and kept them in 'cesium/apps' directory for testing purposes and to avoid CORS issues. Whenever, I try to generate terrain I get error that tile at X:0 Y:0 level 0 as well as tile at X:1 Y:0 level 0 were not found even though I added empty files at the specified locations.

Comment: I tried serving the files via Apache server and enabling CORS via a .htaccess file but its still gives same error

Answer (score 4):

This is now an older question, but I stumbled upon it throughout my research so I'll detail a bit.

After you've managed to generate your terrain tiles, the most obvious at this time option to serve them is https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-server. The server is written in **Go** requires **Go** to be present on the system. It is build with the intention to ease the development and testing of terrain tiles created with [Cesium Terrain Builder tools](https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-builder).

My own objective was to serve `.terrain` tiles from an Apache server and this turned out to be pretty easy, after inspecting in fiddler what cesium-terrain-server is serving and after finding this [exchange of messages](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/cesium-dev&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&hideforumtitle=true&fragments=true&parenturl=https%3A%2F%2Fcesiumjs.org%2Fforum.html#!searchin/cesium-dev/terrain$20server/cesium-dev/tE7AuARBOQQ/k5UelRifbcAJ) (look for Kevin Ring's reply).

Besides **CORS**, essentially terrain files need to have MIME type `application/octet-stream` and if gzipped `Content-Encoding: gzip`. Be careful, only pass the `gzip` header don't `gzip` the files served again if they are already gzipped.

In my `.htaccess` I have the following new lines in place:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
<filesMatch "(.*)\.terrain$">
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
</filesMatch>
```

What I also needed to add is a `layer.json` file in the root of terrain folder, with the following content:

```
{
  "tilejson": "2.1.0",
  "format": "heightmap-1.0",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scheme": "tms",
  "tiles": ["{z}/{x}/{y}.terrain"]
}
```

Now everything just works as intended.